# RewriteRule in virtual host works fine with html but not with https

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I need to change a ReWrite from /applications.html to https://wcmportal.company.be/wps/myportal/intranet/intranet/landing/gprsportal and I'm using the following code for it

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName wcmportal.company.be
    SSLEnable
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{http:iv-remote-address} ^((10)\.(40)\.(62)\.(13))$
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://wcmportal.company.be/wps/myportal/intranet/intranet/landing/gprsportal/$1 [PT,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /applications.html [PT,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

The RewriteRule to /applications.html works fine but the previous line RewriteRule to https://wcmportal.company.be/wps/myportal/intranet/intranet/landing/gprsportal/$1 won't work.

So I think that the RewriteCond is correct but the RewriteRule to the https://... is not correct.

Comment: It's commented out in this configuration. That would stop it from working...

Comment: With the code example I just would show which one works, when I comment the https rewrite out and the /applications one change to a commented one, then it won't work anymore. (eg. #RewritRule /applications and RewriteRule https://...)

Comment: Found the solution for my problem:
'RewriteRule ^/$ https://testportaal.aquafin.be/PublicLogin/portalLogin.html?URL=/wps/myportal/intranet/intranet/landing/gprsportaal [R=301,L]'
It was the ^/$ after the rewrite rule which makes the diffeeence. Original was ^(.*)$